# Prevent Page from Moving when # are used HTML in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am loading a Menu kind of thing in a iframe that uses # links like `http://<location>/page.html#part1`. Each time I click inside the Iframe the whole page (outside iFrame) scrolls to where # is located, how to prevent this? I want just the Menu inside iFrame to move as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` javascript function to change this behavior. Something like this

```
$('#my-navigation-block a').click(function (event){ event.preventDefault(); })
```

Comment: Do you use this code in iframe? Do you add `id='my-navigation-block'` to navigation links wrapper?

Comment: Yup I added the code to the File loaded in the frame, also ID of my link wrapper was "authhd" so I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: I tried that also by looking at the documentation at jQuery.com

Comment: Oh, mea culpa! Fixed up the code. This function should be called on click event.

Comment: What is displayed in javascript console?

Comment: If I use the function like `$('a').click(function (event){ event.preventDefault(); })` then it should prevent all the default function of <a> tag? This should also work here I guess.

Comment: Yes, you right. But in this case all links stop to work correctly.

Comment: JS Console is empty. the iFrame file does not have anything accept of this menu kind of thing.(means no other <a> tag)

Comment: Add `console.log('Clicked!');` after `event.preventDefault();` to debug this and check for correct event binding.

Comment: It was not binded correctly to the element, also When I tried to select just one a link by adding more id and class to it, it worked and showed up 'clicked!!' in console but also lost the functionality of the menu.

Comment: OK. First step worked. 8) Also you can try to add `event.returnValue = false;` for old IE and `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent _bubbling_ event further in DOM.

Comment: The thing is that when I add `event.preventDefault(); ` to it, it loses its menu function also. Will look at it tomorrow.